# Why doesn't EclEmma cover syncronized(MyClass.class)?

Tags: java, concurrency, code-coverage, synchronized, emma

I'm using EclEmma for coverage analysis.

My Java code includes a synchronized(MyClass.class) {} block.

EclEmma says it is only partially covered, event though I've got a unit test in which one thread gets access and another thread is blocked.

Is it possible to get full coverage of synchronized using EclEmma?

Can I annotate the code in some way to tell EclEmma to give this line full coverage?

Kind regards
Roger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure it is possible to get a full coverage, since [issue 2939804](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2939804&group_id=108932&atid=651897) reports:

> EMMA always marks `synchronized(..)` as **partially covered**
>
> Examples:

```
synchronized (lock) // partially covered (yellow line in EclEmma)
{
// ...
}
synchronized (this) // partially covered (yellow line in EclEmma)
{
// ...
}
```

Maybe a different tool ([like Cobertura](http://www.rhq-project.org/display/RHQ/Code+coverage+tools#Codecoveragetools-b%29Toolsthatfullfillscriteria)) would yield a different result? (I have not tested it recently).

---

Update December 2012 (more than 2 years later):

[Nathan D Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/651536/nathan-d-ryan) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715213/why-doesnt-eclemma-cover-syncronizedmyclass-class/3715232#comment19101236_3715232):

> `synchronized` will light to green if the synchronized block contains code that waits on an object monitor, and a test interrupts the waiting thread.
>
> After a little experimentation, I was able to achieve complete coverage of the `synchronized` line if the `synchronized` block completed normally and completed abruptly due to an exception.

Comment: It seems like you are right. I tried this: Object synch = MyClass.class; synchronized (synch) {} but it didn't help, even though my test has one thread waiting and another thread getting the mutex.

Comment: In my experience, `synchronized` will light to green if the synchronized block contains code that waits on an object monitor, and a test interrupts the waiting thread. I've never bothered to dig into the EMMA instrumentation to find out whether this is true in the general case, however.

Comment: After a little experimentation, I was able to achieve complete coverage of the `synchronized` line if the synchronized block completed normally *and* completed abruptly due to an exception.

Comment: @NathanD.Ryan interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @NathanRyan Can you please share an example?

Answer (score 1):

EclEmma uses Jacoco underneath for the coverage analysis.

As explained in Jacoco's (currently non-existing) [JAVAC.SYNC filtering option](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/wiki/filtering-JAVAC.SYNC), the behavior is a result of the byte code generated for synchronized blocks:

> A Java synchronized block gets compiled into two bytecode instructions: MONITORENTER at the beginning and MONITOREXIT at the end of the block.
>
> To ensure that the the monitor is released in any case an exception handler is installed which points to another MONITOREXIT instruction. This exception handler block typically causes partial line coverage which doesn't make sense from the source code point of view.

A related [Jacoco issue 245](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/245) explains how exceptions can be triggered to reach full coverage, should this be desired, as also explained by @nathan-ryan:

1. One test that executes the synchronized block normally
2. A second test that throws (and hence expects) an exception from within the synchronized block.

Comment: (Hi Arie).  So Jacoco doesn't understand that the control flow is *safe*: if you reach the entry point, you *will* reach the exit point.  I imagine that a block with local variables is compiled into a block that initializes the locals, executes the body, and cleans up the locals, with an additional implicit exception handler wrapped around the block that cleans up the locals in case of an exception.   That seems exactly the same in style; yet you can get full coverage on a block by "executing through" it.   (Our Java test coverage tool instruments the source code and wouldn't be confused).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is `MyClass.class` which apparently is implemented using

http://emma.sourceforge.net/faq.html#q.fractional.examples

> Implicit branches due to a hidden Class.forName().  This case is
>   rather unfortunate because it is pretty common and yet the programmer
>   has almost no control over it.
>
> Because Class.forName() can throw checked exceptions, the compiler
>   emits a catch block that rethrows them as unchecked. This catch block
>   hardly ever executes in practice, but it succeeds in marking the line
>   as partially covered.

I missed that on the first read-through.

I will try to re-write my code to get full coverage.

/Roger